# where to use multiprocessing in multi-loop program

Tags: python, parallel-computing, hpc

I am running a program that uses [a lot of] looping to perform a type of bootstrap analysis. The computational step - PCA - can take a long time (60+) seconds, which means that collectively this program could take almost a week to run serially. I have tried using multiprocessing on a high performance cluster - using `concurrent.futures` - but the analysis is just as slow.  I know that misusing multiprocessing can lead to same/worse performance than serial, so I'm wondering at what point in my code this happens.

My analysis program looks like this, serially:

```py
def analysis(dataset, subset_sizes, n_iters):
    for size in subset_sizes:
        for _ in range(n_iters):
            subsampled_dataset = random_sample(dataset, size)
            computation(subsampled_dataset)


for dataset in datasets:
    for _ in range(n_trials):
        analysis(dataset, **kwargs)
```

using multiprocessing, it looks like this:

```py
with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:

    futures = []
    for dataset in datasets: # here, datasets looks like [datasetN_trialN, ...] to use one loop
        futures.append(executor.submit(analysis, **kwargs)) # dataset is part of kwargs

    results = [f.result() for f in concurrent.futures.as_completed(futures)]
```

Should I be calling executor.submit at a different point in my code?

Comment: I understand neither the original code nor the changed one. In the original code, you're just repeating the same analysis `n_trials` times. In the parallelized code, you're calling the `analysis` function without reference to the `dataset` variable.

Comment: You can have a look at the `joblib` library, which tends to perform quite well and has clear tutorials on how to parallelize such concurrent tasks.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth The "same" analysis is different for each trial, because as indicated, the underlying data is randomly sampled for boostrapping. As for the the lack of reference to `dataset`, it's implied to be part of `**kwargs` as is the pattern with using `executor.submit`, but I will make this more clear with a comment.